# Multiple cascade paths Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

My code-first Entity Framework model is as follows:

In my database I have `customers`, `purchases` and `items`.

- A `customer` may have several `purchases`
- Each `purchase` may consist of several `purchased_item`.
- Each `purchased_item` makes reference to an `item`.

So, when configuring my entities with the FluentAPI I have the following configurations:

```
public class PurchaseConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Purchase>
{
    public PurchaseConfiguration (string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".Purchase");
        HasKey(p => p.PurchaseId);
        Property(p => p.Name);

        HasMany(p => p.PurchasedItems) //This is an ICollection of PurchaseItem in the Purchase class
            .WithRequired(pi => pi.Purchase)
            .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.PurchaseId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

public class ItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Item>
{
    public ItemConfiguration (string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".Item");
        HasKey(i => i.ItemId);
        Property(i => i.Name);

        HasMany(i => i.PurchasedItems)
            .WithRequired(pi => pi.Item)
            .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.ItemId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}

public class PurchasedItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<PurchasedItem>
{
    public PurchasedItemConfiguration (string schema = "dbo")
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".PurchasedItem");
        HasKey(rp => rp.PurchasedItemId);
    }
}
```

How I want this to behave is that when you erase a `purchased item` on the DB no information related to either a `purchase` or an `item` is lost. However, if an `item` or a `purchase` is deleted from the db, then the `purchaseditem` is erased too.

However, when I try to update my database I get the following exception:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.PurchasedItem_dbo.Item_ItemId' on table 'PurchasedItem' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: that should work...do you have any other relationships between the three tables?

Comment: No i don't. The only other relationship  is with the `customer` which has cascade delete set to true, so that when a user is deleted all his purchases and items are deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a cycle because a `Customer` has many `Purchase`s and many `Item`s, and each of those entities have cascade paths to `PurchasedItem`. If a customer has many `PurchasedItem`s instead of `Item` -- is that what you mean? -- that would create a cycle as well.

Cascade direction:

```
          +----------+      
          | Customer |      
          +--+----+--+      
             |    |         
             |    |         
+--------+   |    |   +----+
|Purchase| <-+    +-> |Item|
+----+---+            +--+-+
     |                   |  
     |                   |  
     |  +-------------+  |  
     +> |PurchasedItem| <+  
        +-------------+
```

Comment: Your diagram shows accurately the relationship between my entities. Why is this a problem? I want the CASCADE delete to go all the way from Customer to PurchasedItem. Is this possible?

Comment: It's a rule for many databases with cascading actions that you can't have more than one path to any table (see [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). You might have to use triggers or handle it manually. For example, remove the cascade delete between `Customer` and `Item`, and before any deletes of `Customer`, delete its `Item`s first.